# What is the opposite of "xset"? Is there an "xget" command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, x11

My mouse sensitivity sometimes changes on its own, and I would like to see what the acceleration/sensitivity values are at any point. Sometimes I forget my keyboard repeat rate settings and have to feel around for it.

Is there a command like "xset", but to get the current values?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the man of xset :

```
q
The q option gives you information on the current settings.
```

Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: ... I can't believe it was a simple RTFM question. Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm glad it could help you !
BTW, linux is designed so problems are often a RTFM ;)